# Passing a parameterized function in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am writing a parameterized merge sort functionality and passing the less checker as a function.
However, the compiler is throwing following error.

```
type mismatch;
 found   : y.type (with underlying type T)
 required: T
```

Here is my full code

```
def mergeSort[T] (list:List[T], pred:(T,T) =>Boolean):List[T]={
  def merge[T](left:List[T], right:List[T], acc:List[T]):List[T] = (left,right) match{
    case (Nil,_) => acc ++ right
    case (_,Nil) => acc ++ left
    case (x::xs, y::ys) => if(pred(y,x)) merge(left,ys,acc :+ y) else merge(xs,right,acc :+ x)
  }
  val m = list.length/2
  if (m == 0) list
  else {
   val (l,r) = list splitAt m
   merge(mergeSort(l,pred), mergeSort(r,pred), List())
  }
}
```

The problem is at line

```
if(pred(y,x))
```

Everything seems logically correct, can't figure out why this is happening?
help appreciated.

Comment: just replace `merge[T](` with `merge(`.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because in your inner function `merge` you define a type T, it's like you're redefining the one you created in `mergeSort`. Just change `def merge[T]` to `def merge` and keep using T to parameterized your lists `left`, `right`, etc. That way you are telling the compiler "This is the same T I defined above in `mergeSort`".